# Heaven and Earth shall pass away but my word will never pass away

Tags: heaven

Hmmmm

"In the beginning was the WORD and the word was with God"
"Heaven and Earth shall pass away but my word shall never pass away"

Does this mean that the whole universe shall be destroyed and it will return to the time before the beginning again?

Comment: In asking this question, is your frame of reference circular time, or linear/arrow of time?

Comment: 'Before' and 'beginning' cannot be put together. Time began and time shall end.

Answer (score 2):

> And the angel which I saw stand upon the sea and upon the earth lifted up his hand to heaven, and sware by him that liveth for ever and ever, who created heaven, and the things that therein are, and the earth, and the things that therein are, and the sea, and the things which are therein, **that there should be time no longer:**
>
> But in the days of the voice of the seventh angel, when he shall begin to sound, **the mystery of God should be finished**, as he hath declared to his servants the prophets.

Revelation 10:5-7 [KJV]

In these verses it is clear that time shall come to an end. There shall be no more time. Time shall be a thing long gone. An age shall begin that shall have no end.

And that the mystery of God shall be finished : all things shall be revealed, plainly. Those who believe in, and follow, Jesus Christ shall, risen from the dead - see him as he is, without a vail.

> For now we see through a glass, darkly; but then **face to face**: now I know in part; but then shall I know even as also I am known.

I Corinthians 13:12.

This is the hope of the Christian - to be with the Lord for ever.

> Then we which are alive and remain shall be caught up together with them in the clouds, to meet the Lord in the air: **and so shall we ever be with the Lord.**

I Thessalonians 4:17.